# Can this regular expression be improved?

Tags: regex

Here's what I want to match:

```
this_is.ok.com
this_is.another_valid.domain.com
```

And here are some strings I don't want to match:

```
this_one.is_not_ok.com
not_ok.com
also.not_ok
```

i.e., there can be underscores in any part **except** for the ultimate or penultimate part.

The regex I came up with:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]{0,63}?\.)*([a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,63}?\.){1}([a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,63}?){1}$
```

It does seem to work, but I feel like it could be better.

**NB:** Please no discussions about underscores in domain names. Just comment on the regex.

Comment: What regex implementation are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by **ultimate and penultimate part**?

Comment: somepart.anotherpart.penultimatepart.ultimatepart

Comment: I this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/sP1yU3/1) does the job. What do you say ? I kept it without limits because no other rules are specified regarding the length.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this refactored and smaller regex:

```
^([\w-]{1,63}?\.)*([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.)([a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,63})$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oS4dS0/1)

Changes are:

- `\w` - short cut for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- Must keep hyphen at first or last position in character class
- `{1}` is unnecessary and should be taken out
- `{0,63}` should be at least `{1,63}`

Note that this refactored regex takes 106 steps on regex101 site as compared to 124 steps taken by your regex.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "improved" means "shortened":

```
^(\w+\.)+\p{L}+\.\p{L}+$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/tEP7ZYtEZr).